# Добавить скролл блоку, который не влазит целиком на страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

В общем, есть блок содержимое которого вполне влазит в него, но сам блок не влазит на страницу, position у него стоит fixed. У общей старницы есть скролл, но нужно добавить отдельный скролл этому блоку т.к. он не уходит вверх при пролистывании главной страницы. Сколько не пытаюсь реализовать - все в пустую, так что даже скинуть код с какими-то наработками не могу. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: То есть по сути, если блок не влазит на страницу, мне нужно динамически обрезать его высоту, пока он не влезет, а скролл уже тогда сам появится

Answer (score 3):

Вы, возможно, не знаете про свойства `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` для фиксированных и абсолютных элементов. Если задать для фиксированного элемента `top: 0` и `bottom: 0`, то он растянется по высоте страницы от верха до низа и в таком случае не нужно будет ничего динамически обрезать.

Чтобы внутри элемента появился скролл, для него нужно выставить `overflow: auto`

```css
html{height: 100%;}
body{margin: 0; height: 100%;}
   
.fixed{position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 200px; background: #B0C4DE; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="height: 2000px;">Контент сайта</div>
  <div class="fixed">
   <div style="height: 2000px;">Контент фиксированного блока</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```